# How/where to create a void method in CQRS pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cqrs

I am trying to implement the CQRS pattern in clean architecture.

I know If a commads/query then i need to add a folder named as commads/query in applictionLayer.

Now I want to create a void method. not a command or query it is just a void method. and I want to use this again into my queries and commands.

```
public void FormatSomethingHtml(Something something)
{
  something.FinePrint = _helper.FormatHtml(something.FinePrint, something.SiteCode.Name);
  // removed rest      
}
```

I don't know where should create  this method.

If I create this method inside commandHandler, I could not reuse it.
i.e:

```
public class UpdateSomethingCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<UpdateSomethingCommand, Something>
{   
    // removed rest
    public void FormatSomethingHtml(Something something)
    {
        something.FinePrint = _helper.FormatHtml(something.FinePrint, something.SiteCode.Name);
        // removed rest      
    }
}
```

In above method I can use inside UpdateSomethingCommandHandler.
But I could not reuse it in another handler.
ie. When I call like this
`new UpdateSomethingCommandHandler.FormatSomethingHtml(something);` I got error.

Where can create a common method?

Comment: You can register that class as singleton (into your DI) which exposes the `FormatSomethingHtml` method via an interface. And you can require it in your `UpdateSomethingCommandHandler`'s ctor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a utility service and inject it in any query/handler you need.

Ex:

```
public interface IFormatService
{
void FormatSomethingHtml(Something something)
}

public class HtmlFormatService: IFormatService
{
public void FormatSomethingHtml(Something something)
{
  something.FinePrint = _helper.FormatHtml(something.FinePrint, something.SiteCode.Name);
  // removed rest      
}
}
```

In your handler, you would inject it and use it just like any other service

Also, I would consider changing the return type to either Something  so you can update the object and return ot or simply accept a string and return the formatted string like this:

```
public string FormatSomethingHtml(string something)
{
  return _helper.FormatHtml(something.FinePrint, something.SiteCode.Name);
}
```

In your handler/query

```
var something = new Something();
something.Fingerprint = _formatter.FormatSomethingHtml(...)
```